# software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 400)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, quarkus

**Context** : I trying to upload a file to aws s3 via http endpoint built using quarkus framework

**Deployment on EKS** : [image]

**Code Snippet:**

```
@Path("/test")
@POST
public Response testEndpoint(){
    String message = "Hello, this is an arbitrary string message!";
    byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketname)
            .key("your-object-key")
            .contentType("text/plain")
            .contentLength((long) messageBytes.length)
            .build();


    PutObjectResponse putResponse = s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest, RequestBody.fromBytes(messageBytes));

    if (putResponse != null) {
        return Response.ok().status(Status.CREATED).build();
    } else {
        return Response.serverError().build();
    }
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
bucket.name=${BUCKET_NAME:s3://fileupload-test} 
quarkus.s3.aws.region=${AWS_REGION:us-east-1}
quarkus.s3.aws.credentials.type=${AWS_CRED_TYPE:default}
```

Getting below error , any input will be helpful

> 2023-12-13 09:10:22,665 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-2) HTTP Request to /test failed, error id: 60b1f0f5-6c1f-4808-8197-3c3280b778d9-4: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 36F61VZ3D0PHJ2GN, Extended Request ID: 7NvFarwcR64a8KxaKUbjRGpfYcr8TXa1txKoblVWkCgXlVY/0uXnrg+jefCx3DD+2HKowEYoSGc=)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleErrorResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:156)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handleResponse(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:108)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:85)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.handle(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:43)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler$Crc32ValidationResponseHandler.handle(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:93)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseClientHandler.lambda$successTransformationResponseHandler$7(BaseClientHandler.java:279)
> at com.resource.RestResource.testEndpoint(RestResource.java:62)
> at com.datastore.resource.RestResource$quarkusrestinvoker$testEndpoint_0f46b3e633df39664d00b95fa37bc49935818083.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
> at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
> at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:582)
> at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
> at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
> at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
> at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Answer (score 1):

I justed tested your code using JDK 17 in IntelliJ. I am not using the other framework (quarkus) you are. Your code looks ok; however, you should put a txt file extension for the key. You should also debug your S3 Service Client to ensure it's fine.

This AWS S3 Java V2 code works:

```
package com.example.s3.test;

import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectResponse;
import  software.amazon.awssdk.core.sync.RequestBody;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class PutObject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bucketName = "myjunebucket";
        String objectKey = "mytestfile.txt";

        System.out.println("Putting object " + objectKey + " into bucket " + bucketName + " with checksum in algorithm sha256.");
        System.out.println("  in bucket: " + bucketName);

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder()
            .region(region)
            .build();

        putObj( s3Client, bucketName,  objectKey);
    }

    public static void putObj( S3Client s3Client, String bucketName,  String objectKey) {
        String message = "Hello, this is an arbitrary string message!";
        byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucketName)
            .key(objectKey)
            .contentType("text/plain")
            .contentLength((long) messageBytes.length)
            .build();

        try {
            PutObjectResponse putResponse = s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest, RequestBody.fromBytes(messageBytes));
            if (putResponse != null) {
                System.out.println("File was uploaded");
            }
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

See this screenshot. The Response Object is valid:

[image]

Comment: will try this and get back

Comment: @Jaiprasad smac is probably correct here. The output shows status cvode 400 from S3, and HTTP status code 400 means bad request. Something was missing or slightly off in your request to S3 and that's why the endpoint is failing.

Comment: Facing another problem in local environment , when I try to send the file getting sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target , I have added the root certificates from here https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/ to keystore , but still getting the same error , what am I missing

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by certification path. You need AWS CREDS to use AWS Java SDK. Use the default credential provider. To create a Service Client, use the Java V2 code shown above. I have never seen that Sun exception before. Are you still using Java V1 Service Client?

Comment: while running locally providing the below properties

bucket.name=s3://test-fileupload
quarkus.s3.aws.region=ap-south-1
quarkus.s3.aws.credentials.type=default
quarkus.s3.aws.credentials.static-provider.access-key-id=*******
quarkus.s3.aws.credentials.static-provider.secret-access-key=*******

Comment: Using below dependencies 

<quarkus.platform.version>3.5.2</quarkus.platform.version>

    
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkiverse.amazonservices</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>url-connection-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>sts</artifactId>
    </dependency>

Comment: I am able to upload file on to S3 now with access key and id

Comment: However when trying with IRSA with temporary credentials right getting 403 error forbidden

Answer (score 0):

1. From the exception that was thrown it was clear that there was an issue with the request but the error message was not clear about the problem with the request.
2. Built the whole application in springboot(initial app was built on quarkus) and deployed and tried the same , this time the error message was "s3 bucket is not present"
3. The problem was with how the bucket name was specified, it should not be provided as "s3://fileupload-test" and should be just "fileupload-test". After making this change was able to upload the file to s3.